# ASPNET Core: events raised by settings changes using IOptionsMonitor

Tags: asp.net-core, appsettings, ioptionsmonitor

I have created a basic ASPNET Core Web Application (.NET6.0) with MVC pattern.
The goal is to monitor the changes in appsettings.json using events raised by IOptionsMonitor.
My appsettings.json is the following

```
{
  "Example1": {
    "param1": "sample1",
    "param2": "sample2"
  },

  "Example2": {
    "param3": "sample3",
    "param4": "sample4"
  }
}
```

I have create two POCO class to archive settings values :

```
public class Example1
  {
      public string param1 { get; set; }
      public string param2 { get; set; }
  }

  public class Example2
  {
     public string param3 { get; set; }
     public string param4 { get; set; }
  }
```

In the main method of web application I have registered the configuration instances:

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
      var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
      .....
      builder.Services.Configure<Example1>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("Example1"));
      builder.Services.Configure<Example2>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("Example2")); 
      ....
  }
```

Then in the home controller I want to monitor changes to the settings contained in sections example1 and example2. So I've injected IOptionsMonitor for Example1 and Example2 and I've subscribes the onchanges events in this way

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
 {
     private IDisposable _example1listener;
     private IDisposable _example2listener;

     public HomeController( IOptionsMonitor<Example1> example1, IOptionsMonitor<Example2> example2)
     {
         _example1listener = example1.OnChange(ChangeExample1Listener);
         _example2listener = example2.OnChange(ChangeExample2Listener);
     }

     private void ChangeExample1Listener(Example1 example)
     {
         Console.Write("Changed Example 1");
     }

     private void ChangeExample2Listener(Example2 example)
     {
         Console.Write("Changed Example 2");
     }

     ~HomeController()
     {
         _example1listener?.Dispose();
         _example2listener?.Dispose();
     }
}
```

When my web application is up and when I edit a value in section Example1 in appsettings.json
I expect to myself that  ChangeExample1Listener is called. In the same way when I change a value in in section Example2 I expect to myself that ChangeExample2Listener is called according to what I have understood reading the Microsoft documentation

[https://learn.microsoft.com/](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.options.ioptionsmonitor-1.onchange?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0)

but what happens is this: whatever setting I change both listener are called. so this is my output

"Changed Example 1"
"Changed Example 2"

Is this the expected behavior I'm doing something wrong? in the first case there is a way to know if a setting in a given section is really changed?

Comment: I test your code and reproduced the issue as well, but I also found that even if the value I changed is other fields inside the appsetting.json, the 2 onchange event is triggered as well. So it looks like not related with the 2 binding, but related with the defintion for the monitor. Just like we know, for the configuration provider, we have `reloadOnChange: true`, let's say after save the appsettings.json even if we just add some space out of the setions and then delete the spaces and save the file, the 2 events are still be triggerred. I mean the reload might make the monitor to

Comment: to think all the contents are changed. My idea is that, we might create only one POCO for the whole appsettings.json file, or we might create a separate json file to store the example dattat.

Comment: Both good suggestions, thank you. From my point of view, I prefer to have only one appsettings.json but not for technical reasons but because it is easier for maintenance of the software for support staff. But it's strange, I was expecting a slightly more sophisticated method from what I read in the Microsoft documentation. Done like this it simply looks like a FileSystemWatcher.

Comment: yes, and what you mentioned `FileSystemWatcher` informed me that when I test in my side, both of the listener were triggered  and triggered for 2 times. And when I searched for IOptionsMonitor listener was called twice, some of the results pointed to FileSystemWatcher. they might have some relatationship.